# Problem with calling a variadic function template when passing brace initialiser list arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, list-initialization

Consider this function template:

```
template <class... T>
void foo (std::tuple<T, char, double> ... x);
```

This invocation works:

```
using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;
foo ( K{1,'2',3.0}, K{4,'5',6.0}, K{7,'8',9.0} );
```

This one doesn't:

```
foo ( {1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0} );
```

(gcc and clang both complain about too many arguments for `foo`)

Why is the second call a problem? Can I rewrite the declaration of `foo` so that the second call is also accepted?

Thee template parameter T is only used to implement variadicity. The actual type is known and fixed, only the number of arguments varies. In real life the types are different from `int, char, double`, this is just an example.

I cannot use C++17 for this. A C++11-compatible solution is much preferred.

Comment: Is the first argument ever going to be something other than `int`? Probably; you want it to deduce the type from the first argument of the initializer list, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 This is actually unlikely. All the types are known beforehand, only the number of arguments varies. I will be happy with a solution that fixes all the types. (But it cannot be a C-style variadic function). Added this info to the question.

Comment: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dc6ec971a83d4cd), [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3821592f77dd3c62) or [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/061b0d3b9cc96386)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That looks promising for the OP's requirement(C++11). Then why you don't paste them as an answer? (*Just curious*)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki unfortunately 1 doesn't work for me. I have updated the question to reflect the problem more precisely. 2 is no good, there isn't such thing as an empty integer, 0 is just as `int` as any other. 3 looks promising though I don't quite understand it.

Comment: With different types in it, `{1, '2', 3.0}` can't be deduced as `std::initializer_list` or C-style array; and can't be deduced as `std::tuple<T, char, double>` because `{1, `2`, 3.0}` itself isn't a `std::tuple`. I suppose you have to use `K`, or explicit the type calling `foo()` (so `foo<int>( {1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0} );`) or avoid the braces, at least for the first triplet (so `foo(1,'2',3.0, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0})`) to permit `T` deduction.

Comment: @n.m. then what's wrong with providing a sufficient number of overloads like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66e73d7dcad12c2b) ?

Comment: My third hypothesis before require and additional couple of braces: `foo(1,'2',3.0, {{4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0}})`. So the first `1` is deduced as `int` and the following triplets as a `std::tuple<int, char, double>const [2]`

Comment: @max66 OP is more concerned about passing a variable number of arguments, and being able to know how many of them were actually provided, not deducing the first type. and your `foo<int>(...)` idea would actually need to be `foo<int, int, int>(...)`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - uhmm... as far I undestand, also the deduction of the first type is part of the problem; but you're right regarding my `foo<int>()` idea: an additional couple of braces is required.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Many overloads is a cumbersome workaround, I'd rather use an alias or additional braces.

Comment: @n.m. you could use Boost.PP to generate those overloads, and have a single implementation as in my last snippet

Comment: as pointed by Piotr, my explicit-first-type idea (`foo<int>( {1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0} );`) is wrong: also in this case, an additional couple of braces is required (so `foo<int>({{1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0}});`) so you get a `std::tuple<T, char, double> const (&arr)[N]` (where `T` is explicated and `N` is deduced).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generate an overloaded set of constructors:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t M>
using indexed = T;

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Is>
struct initializer : initializer<T, M, sizeof...(Is) + 1, Is...>
{    
    using initializer<T, M, sizeof...(Is) + 1, Is...>::initializer;

    initializer(indexed<T, Is>... ts)
    {
        // ts is a pack of std::tuple<int, char, double>
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Is>
struct initializer<T, M, M, Is...> {};

using foo = initializer<std::tuple<int, char, double>, 20>;
//                                   tuples limit+1 ~~~^

int main()
{
    foo({1,'2',3.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36d9a6f78a3eb19e)

---

Generate an overloaded set of function call operators:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t M>
using indexed = T;

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Is>
struct initializer : initializer<T, M, sizeof...(Is) + 1, Is...>
{    
    using initializer<T, M, sizeof...(Is) + 1, Is...>::operator();

    int operator()(indexed<T, Is>... ts) const
    {            
        // ts is a pack of std::tuple<int, char, double>
        return 1;
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Is>
struct initializer<T, M, M, Is...>
{
    int operator()() const { return 0; }
};

static constexpr initializer<std::tuple<int, char, double>, 20> foo = {};
//                                        tuples limit+1 ~~~^

int main()
{    
    foo({1,'2',3.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0899f0bb77163cc6)

---

Create (or generate with preprocessor macros) a set of overloads that forward arguments to a single implementation:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;

void foo(const std::array<K*, 5>& a)
{
    // a is an array of at most 5 non-null std::tuple<int, char, double>*
}

void foo(K p0) { foo({&p0}); }
void foo(K p0, K p1) { foo({&p0, &p1}); }
void foo(K p0, K p1, K p2) { foo({&p0, &p1, &p2}); }
void foo(K p0, K p1, K p2, K p3) { foo({&p0, &p1, &p2, &p3}); }
void foo(K p0, K p1, K p2, K p3, K p4) { foo({&p0, &p1, &p2, &p3, &p4}); }

int main()
{
    foo({1,'2',3.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0});
    foo({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});
}
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6043ee314322f9fb)

---

Pass as an array and deduce its size (requires additional pair of parens):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N>
void foo(const std::tuple<int, char, double> (&a)[N])
{
    // a is an array of exactly N std::tuple<int, char, double>
}

int main()
{
    foo({{1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}});
 //     ^~~~~~ extra parens ~~~~~^
}
```

[**DEMO 4**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65e5a37e933373de)

---

Use an `std::initializer_list` as a constructor parameter (to skip extra parens):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <initializer_list>

struct foo
{
    foo(std::initializer_list<std::tuple<int, char, double>> li)
    {
        // li is an initializer list of std::tuple<int, char, double>
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo{ {1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0} };
}
```

[**DEMO 5**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f7c9ce14981b73)

Comment: intriguing the first one solution

Answer (score 4):

`{}` is not an expression hence don't have type, argument deduction is concerned about types, special care is taken when the argument used to perform argument deduction is an *initializer list* the template function parameter must have specifics forms, otherwise the parameter is a non-deduced context. A more simplistic example is this:

```
template <class T> struct A { T r; };
template <class T>
void foo (A<T> x);

using K = A<int>;
foo({1}); // fail
foo(K{1}); // compile
```

This is covered by [[temp.deduc.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call)

> If removing references and cv-qualifiers from P gives `std::initializer_­list<P'>` or `P'[N]` for some `P'` and `N` and the argument is a non-empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument, and in the `P'[N]` case, if `N` is a non-type template parameter, `N` is deduced from the length of the initializer list. Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context

and [[temp.deduct.type]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#type-5.6)

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> (5.6) A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified ([temp.deduct.call]).

When you:

- explicitly provide template arguments, it works ... nothing to deduce
- specify the argument as `K{1}`, it works ... the argument is not longer an *initializer list*, is an expression with type.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use C++17 for this. A C++11-compatible solution is much preferred.

With C++11 is a little more complicated (no `std::index_sequence`, no `std::make_index_sequence`) but, if you want maintain the variadic use of tuples... that is... if you substantially want something as

```
foo (std::tuple<int, char, double> ... ts)
```

and if you accept to call a static method of a template struct, you can define a template struct that recursively inherit itself and, recursively, define a

```
func ();
func (K t0);
func (K t0, K t1);
func (K t0, K t1, K t2);
```

where `K` is your

```
using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;
```

The following is a full compiling C++11 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getTypeStruct
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using getType = typename getTypeStruct<T, N>::type;

template <int ...>
struct iList;

template <std::size_t = 50u, std::size_t = 0u, typename = iList<>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t Top, std::size_t N, int ... Is>
struct foo<Top, N, iList<Is...>> : public foo<Top, N+1u, iList<0, Is...>>
 {
   using foo<Top, N+1u, iList<0, Is...>>::func;

   static void func (getType<K, Is> ... ts)
    { std::cout << sizeof...(ts) << std::endl; }
 };

template <std::size_t Top, int ... Is>
struct foo<Top, Top, iList<Is...>>
 {
   // fake func, for recursion ground case
   static void func ()
    { }
 };


int main()
 {
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}); // print 1
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}); // print 2
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});  // print 3
 }
```

If you can use C++14, you can use `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` and the code become a little better, IMHO

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (std::index_sequence<Is...> is)
   -> decltype(is);

template <std::size_t N>
using IndSeqFrom = decltype(getIndexSequence(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getTypeStruct
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using getType = typename getTypeStruct<T, N>::type;

template <std::size_t N = 50, typename = IndSeqFrom<N>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public foo<N-1u>
 {
   using foo<N-1u>::func;

   static void func (getType<K, Is> ... ts)
    { std::cout << sizeof...(ts) << std::endl; }
 };

template <>
struct foo<0, std::index_sequence<>>
 {
   static void func ()
    { std::cout << "0" << std::endl; }
 };

int main()
 {
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0});  // print 1
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0});  // print 2
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});  // print 3
 }
```

It's a pity you can't use C++17 because in you could use variadic `unsing` and avoid at all recursive inheritance

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using K = std::tuple<int, char, double>;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (std::index_sequence<Is...> is)
   -> decltype(is);

template <std::size_t N>
using IndSeqFrom = decltype(getIndexSequence(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getTypeStruct
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using getType = typename getTypeStruct<T, N>::type;

template <std::size_t N, typename = IndSeqFrom<N>>
struct bar;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static void func (getType<K, Is> ... ts)
    { std::cout << sizeof...(ts) << std::endl; }
 };

template <std::size_t N = 50, typename = IndSeqFrom<N>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public bar<Is>...
 { using bar<Is>::func...; };

int main()
 {
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0});  // print 1
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0});  // print 2
   foo<>::func({1,'2',3.0}, {4,'5',6.0}, {7,'8',9.0});  // print 3
 }
```