# C++ Implicit Argument Conversion of Variadic Template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, implicit-conversion, sfinae

AFAIK, In non-templated functions, arguments can be implicitly converted rather than explicitly creating the parameter type:

```cpp
auto foo(const std::vector<int>& input) {
  // implementation here...
}

foo({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }); // implicitly converted to a std::vector<int>
```

I'd like to apply this to variadic templates whose types are known. In my case I've enforced a homogeneous parameter pack so all types are the same:

```
using Range = std::pair<int, int>;

template <class ... Ranges,
  class = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Range, Ranges >...>>>
auto bar(Range&& range, Ranges&& ... ranges) {
  // implementation here...
}

bar({ 1, 2 }, Range{ 3, 4 });
```

Unfortunately, if I try to call `bar({1, 2}, {3, 4});` I will encounter a compile error indicating:

> E0304: no instances of function template "bar" matches the argument list

I realize I can make an initializer list, but I'd like to make it work for variadic templates (homogeneous or heterogeneous).

How can I modify my function `bar` so that arguments of the parameter pack `Ranges` will implicitly convert to `std::pair<int, int>`?

Comment: Template deduction will never do an implicit conversion.

Comment: @NathanOliver aw :( I see. Do you know where that's stated off the top of your head.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.  The rules are in [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4038f239070ebb2d

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Very interesting.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Can you explain what is going on. I am having trouble understanding your code, though it looks good.

Comment: @MichaelChoi I adjusted the code from my previous answer (with more solutions) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53691855/3953764)